# Assets pallet token and democracy pallet

Tags: assets, token, democracy, reserved-balance, locked-balance

Is it possible to use a custom_token created with the `assets_pallet` in the `democracy_pallet` instead of the native_token?

#### *EXPLANATION*

When voting during a referendum, I would like the `balance` parameter of the `vote` extrinsic to be the balance of the custom_token instead of the native token. Every other fees/transactions will still need to use the native_token. Any suggestion, or a concrete example? please?
Kazu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible right now, but will be after there's a `fungibles::Lockable` implementation for Assets (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11446)